# How to use int(input()) in JupyterLite / Pyodide Kernel

Tags: python, input

I tried running the code below in Jupyter served online:

```
term_no = input('Enter number of approximations to use: ')
term_no = int(term_no)
print(term_no)
```

and it returns an error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'PyodideFuture'`

There's no error when I run this in VS code. Is there a bug with Jupyter or should I add something extra?

Comment: Jupyter Online? This might help: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/problem-with-jupyter-online-version/17612

Answer (score 0):

[image: Working in Jupyter]
Your original code is working in Jupyter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, that is not the case that is working in **ALL** Jupyter. It does not currently work in JupyterLite, which is what the OP was posting about. However, the OP didn't include this important point in the post & it is only apparent from 'Pyodide' being mentioned in the error, if one knows what that means. I can see from your screenshot that you are using a typical, full-featured Python 3 ipykernel. That command works in there as you'll see if you look at what is linked by Matthias. Currently, it doesn't work with the web assembly (WASM)-based Python kernel (Pyodide).

Comment: And I should have added at the time, that the solution [there](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/problem-with-jupyter-online-version/17612/2?u=fomightez) linked to by Matthiasin his comments below the OP worked then (and continues to work now) in JupyterLite with the Pyodide kernel. Namely, that solution is to change things to add an `await` to the `input()`, and so the first line would be `term_no = await input('Enter number of approximations to use: ')`. I suggest if you don't want to have to change your code yet want to use an online ability that doesn't require you or others to install ...

Comment: <continued> things on your computer(s) is to use the MyBinder service to get a full, traditional Python kernel in a temporary session served without needing to login or install anything. One such way to launch such a session is outlined at [the bottom of my answer for this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78094369/8508004).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer here even though **Matthias's comment covers it**, since it is still an issue.

The OP's situation involved using the JupyterLite/Pyodide kernel. There are limitations at this time (see more about this below under 'additional option 2') that make JupyterLite/Pyodide kernel different than running things in Jupyter with a traditional full Python kernel and so accomodations can be necessary in some cases, such as when using `input()`.

Therefore, for JupyterLite and the Pyodide kernel try editing your code to add this `await`, like so:

```py
term_no = await input('Enter number of approximations to use: ')
```

Then in the next cell run:

```py
term_no = int(term_no)
print(term_no)
```

This solution is based on [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/problem-with-jupyter-online-version/17612/2?u=fomightez).

##### ADDITIONAL OPTION 1: Adjusting code to a more polished way to collect a number from user:

Ipywidgets work in JupyterLite/Pyodide kernel and offer a more polished way to collect information from a user, and **importantly, the code will be useable in both a typical full Python kernel (ipykernel) and pyodide where ipyiwdgets has been installed.**

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import HTML
import random

slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=0,
    max= 10,
    description= 'Adjust slider to the number of approximations to use:',
    continuous_update=False,
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'},
    layout={'width': '500px'}
)


def on_value_change(change):
    global term_no 
    term_no = slider.value
    output.update(HTML(f"The number of approximations to use is set to: {term_no}"))


output = display(HTML("The number of approximations to use has not yet been set."), display_id=True)
display(slider)

slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

That can be tried in JupyterLite by clicking [here](https://jupyterlite--1343.org.readthedocs.build/en/1343/_static/lab/index.html) and when that session comes up open a new notebook, let the busy indicator in the the upper right go to not busy, and then run `%pip install -q ipywidgets` in a cell followed by the code examples here. You have to use that version of JupyterLite for now because [ipywidgets isn't installing in the stable JupyterLite correctly at this time](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/1342#issue-2176839508). That is temporary and will eventually be fixed on the main, stable branch [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), too.

**Note that with that method of collecting the information there is nothing needed to be run in the next cell, unlike the solution using `await input()`.** You can run the following in the next cell to verify that is indeed the case:

```py
print(type(term_no))
print(term_no)
```

In fact, if you clear the kernel and then run the first code with the slider without actually adjusting the slider you'll then conveniently see a `NameError` when you try to run the cell using `term_no`. This is more convenient than the `input()` way as it provides feedback at several junctures, while avoiding hanging up running a Jupyter `.ipynb` file.

##### ADDITIONAL OPTION 2: Further Details on JupyterLite and an Alternative To Adjusting Your Code

Note that JupyterLite is still labeled as Experimental. See 'Status' [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) where it warns, "**Not all the usual features available in JupyterLab and the Classic Notebook will work with JupyterLite**" and [on the Try Jupyter page](https://jupyter.org/try), note **the 'Experimental' warning highlighted**.
You can use MyBinder for a typical Python-based kernel online without signing in or installing anything on your machine. Go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) and click 'Launch Binder' or [just click here to launch a temporary session](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/HEAD). You can drag and drop into the file navigation panel on the left side to upload your in-progress Jupyter `.ipynb` file from your local computer to the remote temporary session. Keep in mind though this a temporary session on a remote virtual computer; there is no persistence, and so you want to download anything useful you make back to your local system ASAP.